# Church Censuses a one off?

Tags: england, census-records, 1830s, 1820s, herefordshire

I have photocopies of clerical censuses from 1828 & 1838 from a parish in Herefordshire, England.

In fact the details given offer more information than state censuses. Have researchers found these in their area of research or is it a one off?

I discovered them in the records office in Hereford by total chance....I'd like to know if anyone else has found the same.

Answer (score 20):

There are all sorts of other censuses taken by various groups for various purposes. The book "Local Census Listings 1522-1930: Holdings in the British Isles" by Gibson & Medlycott (pub. Federation of Family History Societies, 1997/2001) lists as many as the authors were able to find. If yours are the Much Marcle lists, they are mentioned.

However, don't get too excited - Tarrington also has a census for 1781 in Hereford Record Office, but the other Herefordshire ones (of which there are some 6 or 7) only give names of the householders (plus number of people in the house).

(*Various bookshops appear to have copies*)

Comment: You are right Adrian, it was Much Marcle. What was so important for me was  members who left the family home were mentioned .... where they lived and if daughters what their married name was.

Comment: Wow - sounds like gold dust!

Answer (score 18):

There were a number of censuses of various parishes in Dorset. I have used the [1790 census of Corfe Castle](http://www.opcdorset.org/CorfeCastleFiles/CorfeCastleCensus1790.htm) extensively.

> Transcribed from Hutchins “History and Antiquities of the County of Dorset”, Second Edition, and donated to the Dorset OPC Project by Kim Parker.
>
> The Reverend Hutchins conducted and published this census of Corfe Castle in order to demonstrate to the authorities the utility of such an exercise as an aid to improving the administration of the parish.

There are many fascinating insights into the life and times that would be completely missing in the more formal censuses. It lists, where possible, the occupation and income of the individual.

> HIBBS Mary; 74; Widow; On parish pay
>
> Lodgers:
>
> WELSH Barth.; 74; Mar; On parish pay 1s
>
> WELSH Urs.*; 50; Mar; Knits
>
> HIBBS Mary**; 16; ; Spins; On parish pay
>
> *bast daughter of M. Hibbs
>
> **bast daughter of Urs. Welsh, an idiot

And such gems as:

> HIBBS Robert; 73; Mar; Shoemaker
>
> Robert Hibbs’ wife has eloped

...

> George Keats has only the use of one arm.

...

> UMBY Jane; 31; Mar; Knits; 1s 6d
>
> Husband run away

'''

> PITT W. M.; 36; Mar; Independent Fortune

This is **William Morton Pitt** see [here](http://www.historyofparliamentonline.org/volume/1820-1832/member/pitt-william-1754-1836) for a brief discussion of his parliamentary work.

Comment: +1 for the gems!

Answer (score 3):

The [GenUKI](http://www.genuki.org.uk/) site is a good starting point if you are wondering what local records might be available for a particular location (at the county level for most places and down to individual parishes for some).

Even if GenUKI does not identify particular sources that will interest you, it will list valuable repositories that will reward further searching.

In addition to Gibson and Medlycott (suggested by AdrianB38) you might also chase up a copy of

> *Pre-1841 censuses & population listings in the British Isles* by Colin R. Chapman, Lochin Publishing, c1994.   (A copy is available in the Salt Lake City Family History Library, call no. 942 X27cc 1994.)